# Dynamically creating a javascript/jQuery object to use in the $.css() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, object

### Question:

I'm creating a javascript object to hold css attributes. If I add new variables to the object on the fly, I run into an unknown problem with the jQuery .css() method and nothing happens. *However*, if I initiate the object with the variables I want to/do change, the .css() method works fine.

***In reference to [a post I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566271/cant-set-css-using-variable-jquery), is it necessary that I preset the variables of the object, or is there a way to improve my code to be more dynamic?***
(If I can find a way to add variables on the fly I would be able to set any css attribute, not just the ones I predetermine.)

---

### Extended Explanation:

I'm trying to change the padding and margin values on the fly in my HTML. 
I have created a function that works based on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566271/cant-set-css-using-variable-jquery). However if I simply create an empty object,

```
var cssObject = {};
```

instead of,

```
var cssObject = {
            padding : "inherit",
            paddingBottom : "inherit",
            paddingLeft : "inherit",
            paddingRight : "inherit",
            paddingTop : "inherit",
            margin : "inherit",
            marginBottom : "inherit",
            marginLeft : "inherit",
            marginRight : "inherit",
            marginTop : "inherit"
          };
```

When I add each new css attribute to the *cssObject*, the **$.css()** method doesn't do anything.

```
i.e.

    for(...){
      cssObject[cssName] = cssValue;
    };

    // The cssObject has (for loop).length many attributes.
    // Set new css with cssObject

    $(this).css(cssObject);
```

The *cssObject* gets created (as viewed in the source code and console logs) but the css of *$(this)* doesn't change. **Adversely, When I create the *cssObject* with preset variables using all the same code, it executes fine.**

### Steps of the function:

> 1. Loop through each HTML objects (i.e. div, etc.) with a class name(s) that contains "setspacing".
> 2. The class names of the current object are split into an array.
> 3. Loop through the class names, and stop if the name contains "setspacing".
> 4. The parts of the current class name are split into an array.
> 5. Use class name parts to add new attributes to the css object.

### Sample HTML Code:

```
<div class="full-band">
     <div class="inner-wrapper setspacing-margin-right-left-0">
         <h3 class="setspacing-padding-30px">Bleep Blorp!</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

### jQuery Code:

```
$("[class*='setspacing']").each(function(){
    var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");

    for (var i = classList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (classList[i].indexOf("setspacing") >= 0) {
        var splitName = classList[i].split("-");

        var cssName=null, cssValue=null;
        var cssObject = {}; /*
            padding : "inherit",
            paddingBottom : "inherit",
            paddingLeft : "inherit",
            paddingRight : "inherit",
            paddingTop : "inherit",
            margin : "inherit",
            marginBottom : "inherit",
            marginLeft : "inherit",
            marginRight : "inherit",
            marginTop : "inherit"
          };*/

        for (var j = 2; j < splitName.length-1; j++) {

          if (splitName.length<=3) {
            cssName = splitName[1];
          } else {
            part = splitName[j].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + splitName[j].substring(1);
            cssName = splitName[1]+part;
          };

          cssValue = splitName[splitName.length-1]+" !important";
          cssObject[cssName] = cssValue;
        };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(cssObject)); // EDIT : Added after comment
        $(this).css(cssObject);
      };
    };
  });
```

### Console output when empty object is used:

```
[Log] {"marginTop":"0px !important","marginBottom":"0px !important","marginRight":"0px !important","marginLeft":"0px !important"} (setup.js, line 50)
[Log] {"paddingTop":"0px !important","paddingBottom":"0px !important","paddingRight":"0px !important","paddingLeft":"0px !important"} (setup.js, line 50)
[Log] {"marginTop":"0 !important","marginBottom":"0 !important","marginRight":"0 !important","marginLeft":"0 !important"} (setup.js, line 50)
[Log] {"paddingTop":"0 !important","paddingBottom":"0 !important","paddingRight":"0 !important","paddingLeft":"0 !important"} (setup.js, line 50)
```

Comment: Please post the results of `console.log(JSON.stringify(cssObject));`

Comment: jQuery css() method doesn't support `!important` statement. That's said, you should use `data-*` attributes, not using class to set specific data to element or set style according to class, in CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wolf said in his comments and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/apply-important-css-style-using-jquery) SO question, jQuery css() method doesn't support `!important`, if you try to remove `!important` part then it will works, here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y22Dp/) to test.

Also the inner for loop `var j = 1; j < splitName.length-1;` is starting from the 3rd item, so in case of `setspacing-padding-30px` it will not iterate since the condition `j < splitName.length-1;` is false.

```
$("[class*='setspacing']").each(function(){
    var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");

    for (var i = classList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (classList[i].indexOf("setspacing") >= 0) {
        var splitName = classList[i].split("-");

        var cssName=null, cssValue=null;
        var cssObject = {}; /*
            padding : "inherit",
            paddingBottom : "inherit",
            paddingLeft : "inherit",
            paddingRight : "inherit",
            paddingTop : "inherit",
            margin : "inherit",
            marginBottom : "inherit",
            marginLeft : "inherit",
            marginRight : "inherit",
            marginTop : "inherit"
          };*/

        for (var j = 1; j < splitName.length-1; j++) {// start from 2nd item

          if (splitName.length<=3) {
            cssName = splitName[1];
          } else {
            if(j==1) continue; // if it is the 2nd skip..
            part = splitName[j].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + splitName[j].substring(1);
            cssName = splitName[1]+part;
          };

          cssValue = splitName[splitName.length-1];// remove !imprtant since it is not supported +" !important";
          cssObject[cssName] = cssValue;
        };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(cssObject)); // EDIT : Added after comment
        $(this).css(cssObject);
      };
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are able to modify your code much, but I came up with this much simpler alternative. It uses data attributes instead of classes so you don't have to go about splitting class names.

It is as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/yn7tB/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="full-band">
    <div class="inner-wrapper setspacing" data-margin="0px 0px auto 0px">
        <h3 data-padding="30px" class="setspacing">Bleep Blorp!</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".setspacing").each(function(){
    var attrib = $(this).data();
    var el = $(this);

    $.each(attrib, function (i, e) { 
        el.css(i,e); 
    });
});
```